# Files deleting automatically after 16.04 update

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, updates, stable-release-updates

I have a dual boot with Windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 (After the update from 14.04).

After the update everything ran okay for the first day but now when I select a file (single click and double click), it gets deleted automatically and the file goes to trash.

Also, when I shut down or boot there is a console type graphic which displays somethings very fast before doing anything which did not happen in the first day after the update.

Comment: Using your cell phone, make a movie of the startup messages that appear so quickly that you can't read them. You'll need to use macro mode in the camera. Review the movie, stopping at the appropriate point. Ignore the first message about fsck and clean filesystem, and tell us about any other messages you see.

Comment: I checked and it is the fsck message about clearing orphan inodes

Answer (score 1):

Your file system is dirty. You need to perform a manual fsck. Boot into recovery mode from the GRUB menu. Then choose **root**. At the prompt, type:

**sudo fsck -f /**

repeat until there are no more errors. Then type: **reboot**

Hopefully that should fix your file system, and take care of the problems that you see with deletions. Report back.

Comment: You're OK now, yes?

Comment: I performed the manual fsck and it said 0.3% non-contiguous files.
But the files aren't deleting, yet.  It usually happens after some time of the boot( sounds ridiculous, I know).

But it's working as of now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, it is happening again. Help me ?

Comment: Do you have any software installed on Windows that allows you to read Linux filesystems? Go ahead and do the fsck again and lets see if we have problems there again. Run it more than once, until there are no errors to fix.

Comment: I logged into the Windows and it is happening there as well. Is it a hardware fault ?

Comment: Do you have A HDD or a SSD? In Windows, run a virus scan. In Ubuntu, install gsmartcontrol and smartmontools using Synaptic. Start gsmartcontrol from the dash and run the short SMART test, followed by the long SMART test, and lets see if your HDD/SDD is failing.